# High-level library for Unity Dash?

Tags: unity, application-development, unity-dash, development

I've wanted to write a GTK+ version of Unity Dash for some time. I think it could be useful for Xfce, Gnome Flashback, elementaryOS, etc.

Before I start doing anything about it, I'd like to know if there are any high-level libraries to search Scopes, use filters, etc. A GIR-lib would be very nice.

Does anything like this exist, or am I going to have to do all the dbus stuff myself?

Comment: You might want to look at the libunity package.

Comment: You barely need one for Gnome, especially with [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) extension. As far as I know, Unity is embedded in Ubuntu itself, so may be hard to implement elsewhere.

Comment: There's nothing particularly Ubuntu about Unity. But in this case, I'm primarily interested in Ubuntu, so that's fine in any case. The Unity services is not dependent upon the desktop. Many of the components are used in LXDE, Xfce, KDE and elementaryOS, among others. However, the dash remains unavailable on other desktops, because nobody has created one yet.

Comment: I've looked at libunity-api-doc, but I can't find anything related to Scopes at all. Noticed that this wasn't entirely clear in the question, so I edited it.

Comment: Gnome Flashback is not the same as Gnome Shell. It's the traditional desktop that we used to have in Ubuntu before Unity.

Comment: @jo-erlend-schinstad + it is a matter of about what should be written into a header as script too (concerning homepages) apparently this is ending up in effects to the windows-manager on the installed system too with better appearance on the local system installed in your whatever-device ?! + like the example here + http://www.nosy-x.com/beispiel001.pdf + this was breakthrough for appearance on smartphones concerning browsers like chrome and firefox about two months ago in combination simply html with css +

Answer (score 1):

Gambas3 has an option to install UnitySC which lets you fill out a form and create items which will appear in Unity Dash. The unity plugin, doesnt create an application interface, but you can do that with gambas. Instead, you run UnitySC and fill the form accordingly, to get a link to the item in dash, and Icons, comments, etc. 
[image]

So, when I compiled [Gambas3](http://gambas.sourceforge.net/en/main.html), It did not make an Icon for gambas3 in the Dasah menu. Ah, but I can fix that right now!
here using the UnitySC tool, I added gambas3 to the dash menu, and to the unity bar, with the Icon I screen captured from the gambas website.

[image: Gambas in dash]

[image: Gambas in unity bar]

Comment: I think what he wants to do is make a version of Unity Dash for other DE's like XFCE.

Comment: I didn't read it that way initially, but I see what you mean, now that you have said this.